# How to compute tfd.Normal(0,1) *x + tfd.Norma(2,3)

Tags: tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to build a Bayesian neural network with following structure:
`y1 = w11 x11 w12 x12 + b1`

`y2 = w2 y1 + b2`

Where `w11, w12, b1, w2, b2 ~ N(0,1)`
`x11, x12` are variables are of type `tf.float32`

```
w11 = tfd.Norma(0,1)  
w12 = tfd.Norma(0,1)  
b1 = tfd.Normal(0,1)  
y1 = w11 x11 + w12 x12 + b1
```

How can get random variable y1?

I have tried edward2, but I'd like to implement my own version of variational inference method. So I decided to implement it by myself

```py
    W = tf.cast(np.random.rand(3,2), dtype=tf.float32)
    X = tfp.distributions.Normal([[1,2,3],[2,2,3]],[[3,4,5],[5,6,7]])
    b = tfp.distributions.Normal([[1,2],[2,2]],[[3,4],[5,6]])
    y = tf.add(tf.matmul(W,X) + b)
```

My expected result for y should be a Random variable ~ Normal

I got this

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow_probability.python.distributions.normal.Normal'> to Tensor. Contents: tfp.distributions.Normal("Normal_6/", batch_shape=(2, 3), event_shape=(), dtype=float32). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```